# regex for validating folder name & file name

Tags: regex, preg-match, validation

I want to validate a file name

Name of file or folder should not contain \ / ? % * : | " < > .

Could you please suggest me the regex expression to use in preg_match()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use the [strpbrk()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) function.

```
if (strpbrk($filename, "\\/?%*:|\"<>") === FALSE) {
  /* $filename is legal; doesn't contain illegal character. */
}
else {
  /* $filename contains at least one illegal character. */
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The regex that meets your requirements: `^[^\\/?%*:|"<>\.]+$`

Answer (score 3):

```
new RegExp('^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_!]+$')
```

http://regexpal.com/ try this site

Answer (score 1):

```
new RegExp('^[^\\\\\/\?\%\*\:\|\"<>]+$')
```

its work for me.
Basically it takes:

```
new RegExp('^[^\\/?%*:|"<>]+$')
```