# Check a string for a valid directory name

Tags: php, directory

I need a function, native or user made, that checks if a string is a valid directory name.
I've had a look through the PHP documentation and I can only find the function `is_dir` which checks if it's an existing directory or not and not a valid name for a directory.

Comment: Define "valid directory name" Each OS has its own restrictions. Define what's legal and not, and then validate against that.

Comment: a directory which doesn't exist would be an invalid directory, no?

Comment: You could search for a 'general' directory regex..

Comment: Depending on the used filesystem _everything_ could be a valid pathname.

Comment: I understand different OS's and file systems have their own restrictions. I was looking for a generic way of checking if it is a valid name for a directory. I'm not an expert on file systems so I didn't know that it was entirely possible for anything to be a valid directory name depending on the file system in question. From my point of view it was entirely possible that there might have been a case that a period (.) is not allowed to be used at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you.

See [regex for validating folder name & file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222215/regex-for-validating-folder-name-file-name)

```
if (strpbrk($filename, "\\/?%*:|\"<>") === FALSE) {
  /* $filename is legal; doesn't contain illegal character. */
}
else {
  /* $filename contains at least one illegal character. */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This would work. You can modify the second and third arguments to your needs.

```
if (!mkdir($directory, 0700, true)) {
    die('Error: Illegal directory.');
}
```

Note that this will create the directory if the directory name is valid. However, in my humble opinion (and without knowing your particular use case), this is the preferred way in most languages to handle checking directory name validity. Just attempt create the directory, and if it fails, then tell them that it failed.

The benefits of this is that it keeps your code file system agnostic and it is the least error-prone method to validate and create a directory, since no other process or thread will be able to create a directory between when you validate the directory and when you create it.

The drawback is that this method assumes you want to create the directory immediately.

Of course, there are multiple reasons that `mkdir()` could fail (e.g., insufficient permissions, hardware failure, invalid directory name, etc.), so you may want to display different error messages to the user based on the error. Unfortunately, PHP does not have quite as robust exception handling as some other languages do, but should you want to go down this road, you should be able to use an approach such as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241751/25295) to catch the different warnings that `mkdir()` can generate.

Comment: Maybe you should try this: `mkdir('dirname/test/../temp', 0700, true);` It could     definitely be useful to filter the `$directory` name for certain things like @GregoryBurns suggests in his answer...